# Which logic boards are compatible with Early 2015 13'' MacBook Air?

Tags: macbook-pro, repair, logicboard

I broke the I/O board power cable socket on logic board while trying to clean my computer. AFAICT there is no way that I can somehow solder the socket back onto the logic board to make it work again (please tell me if there is a way to do this and guide me to a resource demonstrating doing this). Hence, I need a replacement logic board.

To do so, I’m planning to buy a “junk” MacBook (broken screen, etc.) for cheap, take out the logic board and replace my logic board with it.

My question is, which models’ logic boards are compatible with an Early 2015 13'' MacBook Air logic board? Which years and makes of MacBook Air's logic board I can use? How about a MacBook Pro's logic board? Which years and makes of MacBook Pro's logic board I can use? Is there a resource (website, etc.) that I can get information about this?

Comment: [Rossman Repair](https://www.rossmanngroup.com/) in NYC can fix that quite easily for a for a very reasonable price.  Probably for less than what you're going to pay for a replacement logic board.  As for find out which logic boards may or may not fit, I would start by looking at the tear downs of the Macs in question on iFixit, but chances are you're limited to the year of that particular Mac.  Apple will often change the location of the mounting holes so that while the board fits, it will never actually install.  Ask me how I know this.

Comment: @Allan You mean by soldering the socket back onto the logic board or by replacing the logic board?

Comment: They will solder the connector back onto the the logic board - often times better than what came from the factory.

Comment: @Allan The website is good but I'm not in US.

Comment: They do international.  They may even be able to point you to someone in your location?  Maybe not, but you won't know until you ask.  As far as finding replacements, see my initial comment.

Comment: @Allan [They don't AFAICT (at least they don't recommend it)](https://www.rossmanngroup.com/shipping/), policy change after the virus maybe. But thank you, I can still ask them for advice and maybe they would be kind enough to provide me some.

Comment: @Utku I don't see anything on Rossman's webpage that says they wouldn't work on your MBA. OTOH, international shipping is a complexity. I'd follow Allan's suggestion and contact them to see if they can recommend a shop physically closer to your location.